# I'm keep getting this error every time I update my post image: Error: slugify: string argument expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file-upload, put

I'm trying to update my post using the slug, the image is uploading to the folder normally but the image string is not updating in the DB, I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong, please help and thanks in advance, this is my code:

```
exports.updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });
    let uploadeImage = req.files.image;
    let uploadPath = __dirname + "/../public/uploads/" + uploadeImage.name;
    uploadeImage.mv(uploadPath, async () => {
      await Post.create({
        image: "/uploads/" + uploadeImage.name,
      });
      post.title = req.body.title;
      post.desc = req.body.desc;
      post.image = req.body.uploadeImage;
      post.save();
      res.status(200).redirect("/posts");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating a record, you are trying to create a new one.

Correct version =>

```
exports.updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug });
    let uploadeImage = req.files.image;
    let uploadPath = __dirname + "/../public/uploads/" + uploadeImage.name;
    uploadeImage.mv(uploadPath, async () => {
      post.image = "/uploads/" + uploadeImage.name;
      post.title = req.body.title;
      post.desc = req.body.desc;
      post.image = req.body.uploadeImage;
      post.save();
      res.status(200).redirect("/posts");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

Instead of "Post.create", you need to use "post.image="

Comment: I get rid of that error thanks to you but now I'm getting  "img src=(unknown)", what I'm missing, the index of image is gone from the database also